# Apps' (those moved into external SD card) icon vanishes from home screens after every reboot

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

My Moto G (2014), running CM12.1, has only 8GB internal storage (5.5GB free to use). This is insufficient for normal use. Therefore, I shifted most of my apps to the external SD card (32GB, class 10, ext4).

But after every reboot all the icons of apps on the SD card vanishes from the screens (they are still available in the drawer).

I think the SD card is not ready when the screens come up and therefore I need to slow down the boot process.

I tried it unsuccessfully, with following little script (`/data/local/userinit.sh`):

```
#!/system/bin/sh
sleep 60
```